# Issue Changing Simple Text on header.tpl using VQMOD in OpenCart

Tags: xml-parsing, opencart, virtualmode

I am trying to use VQMOD for the first time and when I added the code below to my page nothing changed.

I tried to change the `home` link on top right of home page (open cart) to `my home`, but the text did not change. Unfortunately, there was no error on the VQMOD  manager.

My XML code is Below. Do I need to add something to my TPL or make any other changes?

```
<modification>
    <file name="catalog/view/theme/*/template/common/header.tpl">
        <operation>
            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[<?php echo $text_home; ?>]]></search>         
            <add><![CDATA[my home]]></add>   
        </operation>    
    </file>       
</modification>
```

Comment: I've always had the same problem with vqmod, it's just totally unresponsive after install so I reverted to editing the files manually. Is this not an option for you?

Comment: If you've not had anything happen with vQmod after you've installed it, then either the permissions were incorrect on the necessary folders or the install didn't occur on the `index.php` files

Answer (score 3):

You cannot able to replace the header.tpl as in your code.
The VQMOD "Can only search single lines" not a particular variable.

Try this code:

```
<file name="catalog/view/theme/*/template/common/header.tpl">
    <operation>
        <search position="replace"><![CDATA[
          <div class="links"><a href="<?php echo $home; ?>"><?php echo $text_home; ?></a><a href="<?php echo $wishlist; ?>" id="wishlist-total"><?php echo $text_wishlist; ?></a><a href="<?php echo $account; ?>"><?php echo $text_account; ?></a><a href="<?php echo $shopping_cart; ?>"><?php echo $text_shopping_cart; ?></a><a href="<?php echo $checkout; ?>"><?php echo $text_checkout; ?></a></div>
        ]]>
        </search>
        <add><![CDATA[
          <div class="links"><a href="<?php echo $home; ?>">your own link</a><a href="<?php echo $home; ?>"><?php echo $text_home; ?></a><a href="<?php echo $wishlist; ?>" id="wishlist-total"><?php echo $text_wishlist; ?></a><a href="<?php echo $account; ?>"><?php echo $text_account; ?></a><a href="<?php echo $shopping_cart; ?>"><?php echo $text_shopping_cart; ?></a><a href="<?php echo $checkout; ?>"><?php echo $text_checkout; ?></a></div>
        ]]>
        </add>
    </operation>
</file>
```

Answer (score 1):

The one thing I've spotted missing straight away is the modification details at the top are missing

```
<id>Mod Name</id>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<vqmver>2.X</vqmver>
<author>Your name</author>
```

You should really have this code too at the top of the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have include() or require(), or require_once() in the *.tpl files

```
require ('catalog/view/theme/*/template/product/*.tpl');
```

modified to

```
require($vqmod->modCheck('catalog/view/theme/*/template/product/*.tpl'));
```

or

```
<?php
global $vqmod;
require($vqmod->modCheck('file/path/here'));
?>
```

or modify vqmod_opencart.xml

```
<file name="path/ *.tpl">
        <operation>
            <search position="replace" regex="true"><![CDATA[~require\(([^)]+)~]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[require($vqmod->modCheck($1)]]></add>
       </operation>
</file>
```